# Dropbox iOS API thumbnail download gives error

Tags: ios, thumbnails, dropbox-api

I tried downloading a thumbnail with the Dropbox API and I got the errors for each image with thumbnail:

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/thumbnails/dropbox(null)

ERROR LOADING THUMBNAIL: The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 400.)
```

I called the following method to load my thumbnails:

```
[[self restClient] loadThumbnail:obj.url ofSize:@"medium" intoPath:obj.path];
```

My delegates for thumbnail:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadThumbnailFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {
NSLog(@"ERROR LOADING THUMBNAIL: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedThumbnail:(NSString*)destPath {
NSLog(@"Loaded: %@", destPath);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:destPath];
//Do something with my thumbnail
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is the value of obj.url ?

Comment: And obj.path, for that matter. Also, the size should be "m", not "medium": https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#thumbnails

Comment: @MidhunMP The value of obj.url is [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", file.filename] where file is a DBMetadata instance. obj.path is [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:file.filename].